# Use a ReferenceField inside of an ArrayInput/SimpleFormIterator

Tags: react-admin

As the title says. I need to use a ReferenceField inside of a ArrayInput/SimpleFormIterator. I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Versions:

```
react-admin: 3.2.3
react: 16.12.0
```

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<ArrayInput source="specialties" label="">
  <SimpleFormIterator disableAdd>
    <ReferenceField label="Specialties Link" source="ID" reference="specialty" link="show" >
      <TextField source="ID" />
    </ReferenceField>
    <TextInput source="vendorSpecialtyText" label="Vendor Specialty Text" />
  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

There is a resource called specialty and this works inside of an ArrayField in other parts of the application like so:

```
<ArrayField source="specialties" label=" Specialties">
  <SingleFieldList>
    <ReferenceField label="Specialties Link" source="ID" reference="specialty" link="show" >
      <TextField source="ID" />
    </ReferenceField>
  </SingleFieldList>
</ArrayField>
```

Not sure if this just isn't possible within this framework or if I'm implementing this wrong. If there is a way to fix this or a different want to go about this please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/docs/Inputs.md):

> **Note:** `SimpleFormIterator` only accepts `Input` components as children. If you want to use some `Fields` instead, you have to use a `<FormDataConsumer>` to get the correct source,..."

```js
import { ArrayInput, SimpleFormIterator, DateInput, TextInput, FormDataConsumer } from 'react-admin';

<ArrayInput source="backlinks">
    <SimpleFormIterator disableRemove >
        <DateInput source="date" />
        <FormDataConsumer>
            {({ getSource, scopedFormData }) => {
                return (
                    <TextField
                        source={getSource('url')}
                        record={scopedFormData}
                    />
                );
            }}
        </FormDataConsumer>
    </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```

or include input fields

```js
<ArrayInput source="specialties" label="">
  <SimpleFormIterator disableAdd>
    <ReferenceInput label="Specialties Link" source="ID" reference="specialty">
      <SelectInput optionText="{Your description field}"  />
    </ReferenceInput>
    <TextInput source="vendorSpecialtyText" label="Vendor Specialty Text" />
  </SimpleFormIterator>
</ArrayInput>
```